# I have duplicate child elements in my RSS feed. Won't parse it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rss, podcast

I'm pulling RSS data from this URL and this is how their data structure looks like.

```
<item>
<itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
<itunes:season>6</itunes:season>
<itunes:episode>49</itunes:episode>
<itunes:season>6</itunes:season>
</item>
```

It has duplicate child element itunes:season. How do I correctly parse it in JavaSCript? Any help will be apprciated! :)

here is the gist of my code:

```
success: function(data) {
   .find("item")
     .each(function() {
       const el = $(this);
       const seasonLS = el.find("itunes\\:season").text();
       const episodeLS = el.find("itunes\\:episode").text();  
    };
```

I tried fetching it by the child name but the duplicate child names are throwing it off.

Edit:

Sorry for the unclear question. Here is more information.

1. The expected output for `<itunes:season>` is `6`. This one spits out `66`.
2. `.find()` is chained on below:

const RSS_URL = `*** URL ***`;

```
$.ajax(RSS_URL, {
  accepts: {
     xml: "application/rss+xml"
  },
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $(data)
      .find("item")...
```

Comment: We need more information here .  You aren't clear on what your *expected* parsed data should look like ..

Comment: WHat is `.find` chained to?

Comment: @Zak Hey! The expected parsed data should be 6. The one in my code parses 66. I'm assuming it's because of the duplicate child values.

Comment: @GetSet Updated my answer to add this information. It is chained on to:
const RSS_URL = *** URL ***;

    $.ajax(RSS_URL, {
        accepts: {
            xml: "application/rss+xml"
        },

        dataType: "xml",

        success: function(data) {
    .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to just grab those two elements regardless of how many there are .. Why not just create a DOM object, and search by tag .. Then find the first index of each:

```js
const htmlString = `<item>
<itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
<itunes:season>6</itunes:season>
<itunes:episode>49</itunes:episode>
<itunes:season>6</itunes:season>
</item>
<item>
<itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
<itunes:season>7</itunes:season>
<itunes:episode>55</itunes:episode>
<itunes:season>5</itunes:season>
</item>`;

const domParser = new DOMParser();
const docElement = domParser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html").documentElement;

var emCollection = docElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (var i = 0; i < emCollection.length; i++) {
  const seasonLS = emCollection[i].getElementsByTagName('itunes:season')[0].innerHTML;
  const episodeLS = emCollection[i].getElementsByTagName('itunes:episode')[0].innerHTML;
  console.log("Episode: " + episodeLS + "\n Season: " + seasonLS)
}
```